# how to create a jar including all dependencies from the command line only?

Tags: java, maven

I would like to avoid modifying the pom to include plugins, etc. How to create a jar which includes all dependencies exclusively from the command line?

e.g.

```
mvn package ....
```

Comment: It already include all dependencies using `package` no?

Comment: @YassinHajaj - no, `package` only includes the code under `src/`

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: @gregwhitaker - ok, but still requires modifications to the pom. I would like to avoid modifying the pom for this requirement.

Comment: @beluchin Why do you want to avoid modifying the pom?

Comment: @lexicore - it is a one-off and I want to avoid forgetting to remove the pom mods

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) for that:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

It will create a second jar that includes all dependencies. After putting the configuration in your pom, run `mvn package` and it will create the second jar file for you.

**Edit:** I just read the comments. It will be impossible to achieve this without modifying the pom.

Comment: consider removing your answer as it does not directly address the original question. Thanks.

Comment: In what way doesn't it answer the question? What you want to achieve is not doable without pom modifications, hence I provided you an alternative solution. Also, believe me, this won't be the last time that you build a runnable jar :)